LibreCAD cannot access disks or USBs on Fedora
I need to use librecad but I can only see the system drive. It does not allow you to see other partitions, disks or USB. It is the only application that has this problem, all system applications were installed from Discover.
OS - Fedora 40
LibreCAD - 2.2.0.2
Thanks

Access (files under) a mountpoint is not the same thing as "access disks or USBs" though. You can really just traverse down from / until you reach wherever the file you need resides. Probably somewhere under /media or /run/media. If you need the drive-mountpoint "mapping", try lsblk -f or findmnt. If a drive has not been (auto)mounted yet, try udisksctl (or just click it in e.g. Nautilus). Or does the file dialog provides no way for you to traverse down from /?

With the lslb -k you can see the mounted disks. sda(sda1 ntfs // sda2 ext4  // sda3 swap )                              sdb (sdb1 vfat // sdb2 ntfs /run/media/user/N1 // sdb3 ntfs /run/media/user/N2) sdc (sdc1 ntfs  /run/media/user/SD). If you execute a .dxf file from the SD, the OS recognizes it and opens it with LibreCAD, but when you try to save the changes from the application you only see /home/user

See what flatpak info org.librecad.librecad outputs. If it doesn't give you an error, probably you are using a flatpak build/version of librecad, in which case you may need / try flatpak override --filesystem=/run/media org.librecad.librecad.

Uninstall the discover version and install from flatpak. The problem persists when trying to open, save changes or import blocks .dxf but if I export to an image or PDF all disks can be accessed.
